# Is there an easy way to show Wordpress posts in kivy/python app?

Tags: python, wordpress, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to make an app with kivy, but am wondering if I can connect it to a Wordpress database, I want to show the wp posts within the kivy app, is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: What have you tried or researched so far?

Comment: I tried using a python module to connect to a wp site with username and password, but when trying to list the posts I get a urllib parser module not found and installing it failed, so if there is an easier way to do that - would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress provides a REST API. You can use it to get posts in JSON format using an HTTP request and do whatever you want with the data.

Comment: Oh, cool I’ll look into the rest api then.